# RxJs 6 chaining multiple subscriptions

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I have an Angular 6 app. I'm upgrading rxjs to 6.

In the previous version of the app I had to make a call like this...

I call an observable 
 Do something with its result
 Then call another observable using the value from the last
 Do something with its result

Do do this used concatmap. The code looked like this...

```
this.service1.getData().concatMap(d1 => {
            this.d1Local = d1;
            return this.service2.getData(d1);
        }).subscribe(
            this.d2Local = d2,
            error => errorFunction);
```

I'm trying to rewrite this using rxjs6 and the pipe keyword and without concatmap.

I currently have...

```
this._LocationService.getLocation()
    .pipe(           
        map(location => {
            console.log(1);
            this.location = location;
            return this._GeoCoderService.getAddress(location)
                .pipe
                (map(address => {
                this.address = "You are near " + address;
                    this.showSpinner = false;
                }
                ))
            }
        )   
);
```

I am never seeing '1' being logged to the console.
Any ideas how I should be doing this?

---

UPDATE:

I know have the below code. I think its almost right how ever I am not seeing the last condole.log print 1....

```
this._LocationService.getLocation()
    .pipe(map((location: ILocation) => {
        this.location = location;
        return this._GeoCoderService.getAddress(location);
    })
        , catchError(error => { this.showSpinner = false; return throwError('Something went wrong!') })
    ).subscribe(
        tap((address: string) => { console.log(1) })
    );
```

What am I missing?

Comment: If `this._GeoCoderService.getAddress` returns an Observable you need to use `concatMap` (or `mergeMap` in this case). You also need to subscribe at the end of the chain.

Comment: Why would you do a `.tap()` inside a `subscribe()`?

Comment: You should not `tap`in  `subscribe` - just `subscribe((address: string) =>  console.log(1));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't get rid of the `concatMap` operator. It is best suited for the job. To make things cleaner, I wouldn't store away the data inside the `map` operator either. For side-effects, `tap` is the best option for readable code.

```
this.service1.getData().pipe(
        tap(d1 => this.d1Local = d1),
        concatMap(d1 => this.service2.getData(d1),
    ).subscribe(
        d2 => this.d2Local = d2,
        error => errorFunction);
```

Comment: Concatmap has been removed from rxjs6 though so I want to pull it out of my code.

Comment: No, concatMap has not been removed from RxJS6. It's still there in `rxjs/operators`. It's the simplest way to work with higher order observables. I doubt that this family of operators will ever get removed from RxJS.

Answer (score 2):

After `pipe()` you should `.subscribe()`
(observables are lazy and if you just do `pipe()` it does not trigger but `subscribe` does)